# Check length of String passed from Model

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC and I'm having some issues checking, in my view, if a string passed from my Model is empty or not.

I have a `<p>`-tag, inside a `<div>`,  like so:

```
<div class="category-text">
    <p class="sidebar-text">@Html.Raw(Model.Text)</p>
</div>
```

Which in some cases will hold text and in some cases won't, so I want the whole div containing this `<p>`-tag to not display IF the text is empty. I wrote a jQuery function for this:

```
if ($(".sidebar-text").text().length) {
    $(".category-text").show();
}
```

This function seems to be working. If I for example hardcode "asd" into the `<p>`-tag and log it in the console it gives me "3", which is how I expect it to be working.

My problem is that using `@Html.Raw(Model.Text)` always returns 0, which makes the whole `category-text` div not show. I know for a fact that Model.Text has value, and using `@Html.Raw(Model.Text)` somewhere else in my view proves that text is actually in the `Model.Text`-object.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the `<div>` with an `if` statement, like so:

```
@if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Text))
{
    <div class="category-text">
        <p class="sidebar-text">@Html.Raw(Model.Text)</p>
    </div>
}
```

This will prevent the whole `<div>` from rendering to the response it wont be available in the DOM.

If, however, you need the `<div>` present in the DOM but invisible, due to the empty paragraph, you could set the CSS visibility property on the server. E.g.

```
<style>
    .invisible { visibility: hidden; }
</style>
```

Then the HTML for the `<div>` would look like this:

```
<div class="category-text @(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Text) ? String.Empty : invisible)">
    <p class="sidebar-text">@Html.Raw(Model.Text)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo, make `(Model.Text)` :)

Comment: Awesome. I only had to show the div, and it worked well. Thanks!